# Relay or Transistor as low DC switch

Tags: transistors, switches, relay

I am working on a project for a watering controller where I would need to turn on or off an solenoid valve (electric valve), my first thought would be to use a relay, but I know relays are good for things like 110V/220V AC, but I feel like it would be too overkill for 9V/12V DC.
Would a transistor work as a switch for 9 to 12 volts? Or is a relay still a better option?

Comment: May be related, if not duplicate. [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10092/relay-vs-transistor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relays are still used and with good reason. In your case:

- The relay separates your logic circuit from your high-current and higher voltage pump circuit.
- Any faults on your pump circuit will not affect your logic circuit.
- A faulty relay can often be a plug-in replacement.

A transistor is cheaper but requires that the common line must be shared between both circuits.

Comment: And the OP will still need a transistor to turn on the relay as the I/O pin almost certainly can't handle the relay current required. So the transistor is still in the picture. Just not the same picture.